# I am trying to use the scp command to copy a directory from a local ubuntu machine to a remote ubuntu machine

Tags: ssh, authentication

The purpose of this script is to establish an SSH connection with a remote host and then use the `scp` command to copy the `/home/desktop/Documents` directory to the target directory `/home/haca/desktop`

Script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT="cd Desktop; pwd;  echo -e 'PASSWORD' | sudo -S scp -r /home/desktop/Documents/ haca@192.168.0.118:/home/haca/desktop"

HOSTS=("192.168.0.118")
USERNAMES=("haca")
PASSWORDS=("******")
for i in ${!HOSTS[*]} ; do
     echo ${HOSTS[i]}
     SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${PASSWORDS[i]}}
     sshpass -p ${PASSWORDS[i]} ssh -l ${USERNAMES[i]} ${HOSTS[i]} "${SCR}"

done
```

I omitted the password from this script for obvious reasons.

Not sure why it is not working this is the output I recieve when running the script:

```
192.168.0.118
/home/haca/Desktop
[sudo] password for haca: Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you commenting on your own question instead of editing it? Please use the "code formating" button to fomrat your script in a way that's readable, as well!

Comment: Can you `scp` to the target machine with `echo <password> | scp haca@...` from the command line?

Comment: I suggest you try much harder to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first time a Linux host is booted it typically generates a set of SSH "host keys". When you connect to a host the host sends your SSH client its keys. If your machine has never talked to this host before it doesn't recognize the keys and so your client gives a warning like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'irobot (192.168.1.1)' cant be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:di+nebThBUTmW57O8sMVtP3X2YGenftovtoPRogvBvI.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

If you say "yes" the hosts keys are added to the file:

```
$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```

So that the next time you connect to that host it will be recognized and SSH will connect without prompting you about host keys again. The error:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

Is because the host doesn't have the host keys installed. There are several ways to solve that, the simplest is just to run the steps manually as SSH will prompt you to save the host keys on the machine - after that the automation should run without issue.

Alternatively you can use the `ssh-keyscan` utility to store the host keys, something like:

```
ssh-keyscan SOME_HOSTNAME >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```